# Referencing null in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm not sure how to reference the null value I'm seeing below. I believe this null value was generated as a result of a LEFT JOIN but now I want to replace this String and have no way of referencing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to reference this NULL value in mobile_type  field you can use

```
WHERE mobile_type IS NULL
```

or if this is result of LEFT JOIN - you can modify your respective SELECT - instead of something like `SELECT mobile_type` - you can use `SELECT IFNULL(mobile_type, 'none')` (for standard sql)

Comment: IFNULL worked in the SELECT statement. Thanks so much!